# Having trouble with proving $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{(Re(z))^2}{|z|} = 0$ using the epsilon definition

Tags: epsilon-delta

So, I got up to expanding $\frac{(\Re(z))^2}{|z|}$ to $\frac{z^2+2z\overline z + \overline z^2}{4|z|}$ but I don't see other sequences that converge to $0$ to spark inspiration on how to continue.

This one has just really thrown me off. Any tips?

Edit: Actually

$$\frac{(\Re(z))^2}{|z|} = \frac{r^2\cos^2(n)}{|r|e^{in}} = \frac{|r|^2\cos^2(n)}{|r|e^{in}} = \frac{|r|\cos^2(n)}{e^{in}}$$

and $$\lim_{r\to0}\frac{|r|\cos^2(n)}{e^{in}} = 0\frac{\cos^2(n)}{e^{in}} = 0$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Sure.  I was going to say $|Re(z)| < |z|$ which implies $\left |\frac {(Re(z))^2}{|z|}\right| < |z|$

Comment: @user317176 Thanks, but is $\frac{(Re(z))^2}{|z|}$ = $|\frac{(Re(z))^2}{|z|}|$?

Comment: No, but if $|f(z)| = 0$ then $f(z) = 0$

Comment: @user317176 So if $\lim_{z\to0}|\frac{(Re(z))^2}{|z|}| = 0$ then it follows that $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{(Re(z))^2}{|z|} = 0$?

Comment: Indeed it does.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative we can also use that by $z=x+iy$ and $x\neq 0$

$$\frac{(\Re(z))^2}{|z|}=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le \frac{x^2}{|x|}=|x|\to 0$$